# How to print dd-mm-yyyy at url in Kantu (UI.Vision)?

Tags: javascript, date, web-scraping, browser-automation, kantu

I am using Kantu (now known by a new name [UI.vision](https://ui.vision/)), a browser extension to do things on websites automatically, based on Selenium (I assume so).

I want it to print dd-mm-yyyy at the website's url, for example `www.webstite.com/date=dd-mm-yyyy`, from any day of the past to present. Let say from 01/02/2003 to 18/03/2020, print every single day.

One of the ways to achieve that is to use Kantu's `executeScript` command. It can execute a Javascript code body (meaning no `<head>`, only the code inside the `<body><script></script></body>`)
You can look [here](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/executescript) for better understanding about that command.

And then maybe I need to `store` the output to a variable and print that variable.

So perhaps the problem is of writing Javascript.

If anyone is using Kantu and understand it, do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

On the [executeScript](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/executescript#code) documentation page you find some good examples. The one that you need is "Get todays date in YYYY-MM-DD format".

```
executeScript | var d= new Date(); var m=((d.getMonth()+1)<10)?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1); return d.getFullYear()+"-"+m+"-"+d.getDate(); | result
```

The `${result}` variable has the date now.